# Multiple drop down buttons showing same data but coded differently

Tags: html, bootstrap-4, dropdown

I have a card on my page with two buttons, they both have functioning drop down lists but the second button is mirroring the first button even though the list data is completely different.

Edit 1: removed extra li and added /ul to the end of each list. My example here is slightly different than the actual code as I had to revise it for privacy.

Edit 2: To clarify, per the example below: both button drop downs show the "link name" menu item but the second drop down is coded to say "link name 2".

Edit 3: I can comment out the entire second list and it still shows the first list on the second button.

**Note: Using bootstrap 4**

```html
    <div class="card text-center">
                <div class="card-body">
                  <h4 class="card-title">Quick Links</h4>
                  <p class="card-text">Select your quick link ticket through the drop down menu.</p>
                 
                           
                            <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button"  data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" id="quicklinkbtn">
                              Select Quick Link
                            </button>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu multi-level" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu">
                                <li class="dropdown-submenu">
                                  <a class="dropdown-item" tabindex="-1" href="#">Location Name</a>
                                  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                    <li>
                                      <a data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Hover text overview of ticket type" class="dropdown-item menuLink" tabindex="-1" href="#">Link Name</a>
    </li>
    </li>
                                    </ul>
                                   </ul>
    <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button"  data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" id="restrictedbtn">
                              Restricted Quick Links
                            </button>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu multi-level" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu">
                                <li class="dropdown-submenu">
                                  <a class="dropdown-item" tabindex="-1" href="#">Location</a>
                                  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                    <li>
                                      <a data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Hover text for link" class="dropdown-item menuLink" tabindex="-1" href="#">Link Name 2</a>
                                    </li>
    </li>
    </ul>
    </ul>
    </div>
    </div>
    
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: I'm not sure if that's causing your problem,  but you didn't close any of yours lists

Comment: Yep, try what @K.P. said. Make sure you add the `</ul>` and `</li>` where necessary otherwise the browser won't know when it actually ends.

Comment: Updated my snip above to include closing components. Added more info in original question as well.

Comment: @Tyrant_Tommy: try to wrap them in two separated DIVs. something like: `<div style="float:left !important;"><button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle"......</ul></div>` and the other one same: `<div style="float:left !important;"><button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle".........</ul></div>`. and around both just keep the rest of you code: `<div class="card text-center">
  <div class="card-body"><h4 class="card-title">Quick Links</h4><p class="card-text">Select your quick link ticket through the drop down menu.</p>.........</div></div>`. This way will help.